# The use of the verb "call" in the sense of "think"

Tags: word-usage

Does the following sentences sound natural?

> Can you **call** yourself a good teacher?
>
> You did the excellent job, so you **call** yourself a genius.

What I am trying to say that I think the persons has some qualities to be considered something.

Comment: *You did **the** excellent job* is not natural sounding. It's possible, in a narrow context, to use the definite article, but as a general statement it should be *you did **an** excellent job*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentences sound natural.

Call in these sentences doesn't mean "think" but implies you'd declare or "name" yourself the thing.

> Can you call yourself an artist?

Isn't about if the person thinks they are an artist, it's about if the person claims they are an artist.  The two are often related, but they are slightly different ideas.

One example of where claiming to be something differs from believing you are something is Engineering.  Even if a person believes they can solve engineering problems, even if a person has attended University and obtained an engineering degree, and even if they are working as an engineer, they cannot call themselves an Engineer until they pass a State Certification Board's requirements.

So the question

> Can you call yourself an Engineer?

Might not be a question about their belief, but just a question about their legal right to use that title.

Comment: "they cannot call themselves an Engineer until they pass a State Certification Board's requirements." - USA specific.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, and many countries have similar standards.  Few countries permit yourself the liberty of calling yourself "Doctor" without some form of government approval.  Lawyer is another controlled term, for most countries.

Comment: Unfortunately, these days, many people who are technicians or not even that, call themselves 'engineers', e.g. plumbers say they are 'water supply engineers'. My dad was an electrical engineer who managed power networks, commissioned generating plant, etc, and it really annoyed him if people thought he spent his days wiring lamps or outlets. "That's what electricians do' he used to say.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I know, they even called me a software engineer once.  That said, I was a software engineer who worked for Engineers who build electrical distribution networks.  So, I learned this detail early on.  It's a shame that "task-engineer" became so commonplace.  The real engineers work a lot harder than most might think to earn their title..

Comment: My father said an engineer is someone who can make, for one pound, what any damn fool can make for five pounds.